# Audience Targeting in FullTextSqlQuery

Tags: sharepoint-2007, full-text-search

I am trying to perform a search for documents within a SharePoint site, but I need to apply audience targeting to the results before they are displayed to the user.

I am however struggling to either (a) retrieve the target audience settings within the original query...

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID)) {
    using (FullTextSqlQuery fullText = new FullTextSqlQuery(site)) {
        fullText.QueryText = @"select Title, Path, Description, TargetAudience from scope() where ((""scope"" = 'All Sites'))"
            + @" and IsDocument = 1 and freetext(*, '{0}')";
        fullText.QueryText = string.Format(fullText.QueryText, this.documentFilter.AllOfTheseWords);
        fullText.ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults;
        ResultTableCollection resultTableCollection = fullText.Execute();

        allofTheseWords = new DataTable();
        if (resultTableCollection.Exists(ResultType.RelevantResults)) {
            allofTheseWords.Load(resultTableCollection[ResultType.RelevantResults], LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
        }

    }
}
```

or (b) retrieve the list item id (guid) from within the original query so that I can then tie up each result to the original list item (and therefore apply the audience targeting using the list item.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found a way to retrieve the original list item based upon the URL returned from the full text query and then apply the audience targeting test to the list item.